# Running Ubuntu on Windows (WSL) leads to SystemOutdated Error when trying to install bun

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I tried to install `bun` https://bun.sh/ on my windows machine and use Ubuntu 20.04 on WSL.

After running `curl https://bun.sh/install | bash` and trying to run a command I get the following error:

```
coding@DESKTOP-PO2H28R:~$ bun create app
Fetching package.json... error: Failed to initialize network thread: SystemOutdated.
```

I ran `apt-get update` and `apt-get update` before which did not solve the issue. I also ran `wsl --update` which did nothing.  Does anyone know how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce this when attempting to run `bun` under WSL1/Ubuntu 20.04.  However, WSL2 works fine, at least for this command.

Check your release by running `wsl.exe -l -v`.

WSL1 does not provide a real Linux kernel, but rather a pseudo-kernel that acts as a syscall translation layer between the Linux and Windows APIs.  It's pretty dang impressive, but it's quite a ways from 100% implementation.  The [last report I saw](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/wsl/testing-the-windows-subsystem-for-linux#ltp-in-the-creators-update) showed that about 73% of the LTP tests passed on WSL1.

That may sound low, but those APIs seem to provide upwards of 99% of the functionality for [most common developer tools and languages](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/wsl/testing-the-windows-subsystem-for-linux#scenario-testing) at the time.

However, it's not surprising that a new and extremely (apparently) optimized runtime like Bun might rely on something that isn't implemented in WSL1.  The networking stack is definitely a big area where WSL1 and the Linux kernel differ, since the Windows and Linux architecture is quite different.  The error that we're seeing definitely indicates that the problem is in that area.

If your system is capable of running WSL2, then you'll want to run Bun under a WSL2 instance.  You can keep your existing WSL1 Ubuntu if you'd like (there are some advantages of WSL1) for other purposes, or you can convert it entirely.

See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1416645/1165986) (among others) for some details of how to back up and clone the existing distribution.  When you do the `--import` step, specify the `--version 2`.

Or, after (optionally) backing up, use `wsl --set-version <distro_name> 2`.

Comment: thank you man, you were right, ubuntu ran unter version 1!!